# How can I set up a OpenVMS VM environment

Tags: edi, openvms

I am looking to set up a VM running openVMS if there is a free version or possibly freeVMS? I essentially want to set up a VMS environment with the EVE and EDI editors.

I run a Mac so I'd like to set it up on that, I could sort out a PC if necessary but I'd rather not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not going to use OpenVMS commercially you can get free licenses from [here](http://www.openvms.org/pages.php?page=Hobbyist). They will also provide you with access to downloadable media once you register.

The only free emulator I'm aware of that runs on OS X is the VAX emulator in SIMH.  See [the SIMH github project](https://github.com/simh/simh).

There are various Alpha emulators; most assume a Windows host, though I think there is now one that runs on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, should I choose the "Digital Equipment Corporation VAX-11/780" or "Digital Equipment Corporation MicroVAX 3900"? 

Also for anyone else wanting to do the above you need to become a member of a HPUG to get the licenses. If you are familiar with telnet then http://decuserve.org/ is free to join, the UK one costs £54 for a hobbyist license.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual machine running Windows XP on MAC OS X, and install PersonalAlpha (by Stromasys) in there. All you need then are the OpenVMS Hobbyist Licenses and media to install from.

BTW, these are the free Alpha emulators running on Windows I know about:

- [PersonalAlpha by Stromasys](http://www.stromasys.ch/personalalphaplus/)
- [FreeAXP by Migration Specialties](http://www.migrationspecialties.com/FreeAXP.html)

For linux:

- [AXPNCE by Stromasys](http://www.stromasys.ch/axpnce/)

Commercial Alpha (and VAX) emulators:

- [vtAlpha by AVTware](http://www.avtware.com/alpha%20replacement.html). This is basically a modified Linux with an Alpha emulator. They have no plans for a free version for non-commercial use.
- [Avanti and AvantiFlex by Migration Specialties](http://www.migrationspecialties.com/Emulator-Alpha.html).
- [Charon AXP products by Stromasys](http://www.stromasys.ch/virtualization-solutions/virtual-alpha-on-windows/)